# After purchase is successful,related function does not work

Tags: swift, in-app-purchase, segue

I want to perform segue, after purchase is successful. But anyway my code does not work. devam() function is a function which must perform segue. But even case. purchased. The function does not work. I know purchase is successful but the action is not taken.

for aTransact in transactions {

```
        switch aTransact.transactionState {

        case .deferred:
            print(aTransact.payment.productIdentifier,"beklemede")
            break
        case .failed:
            queue.finishTransaction(aTransact)
            print(aTransact.payment.productIdentifier,"başarısız")
            break
        case .purchased:
            devam()
            print(aTransact.payment.productIdentifier,"Tamamlandı")
            break
        case .purchasing:
            print(aTransact.payment.productIdentifier,"Alım İşlemi Başladı")
            break
        case .restored:
            queue.finishTransaction(aTransact)
            print(aTransact.payment.productIdentifier,"önceki alım yenilendi")
            break
        default:break


        }

    }
```

func devam() {

```
        let board : UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)

        let tabBar = board.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "tabBar") as! ViewControllerSat2

        window?.rootViewController = tabBar



    }
```

Comment: how do you define window ?

Comment: not at the extension at main class ------- var window : UIWindow?

Answer (score 0):

It seems `window` is `nil` so make it

```
(UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).window!.rootViewController = tabBar
```